# Computer keeps on hanging

Tags: windows-10, repair

I am using Windows 10 64 bit with 8 GB RAM. My system is kind of in a hanged state after some time. The computer is still hanged,while typing this post(thats why unable to attach screenshot), the icons of some of items at Windows task bar is also not visible. Its still in a hanged state. I tried running sfc but it runs till 72% and got stuck.I also tried running sfc in safe mode but still the same result.Then i did a chkdsk and then "DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth" to restore Windows 10 image and then tried to run sfc again but again it gets stuck at 72%. 
I have lots of software installed in my system and do not have such restore points such that all my softwares and data could be preserved. I also tried system repair by making bootable usb of windows 10 but repair had only two options fresh install by deleting all the items, 2) installation by deleting all apps and setting but keeping user files safe.

Kindly suggest me to how to fix windows without losing any data.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 is running (even if poorly), and so try the above from the Media Creation Link (creates an install setup matched to your system).  Try first Keep Everything and see if that works. Otherwise, if so badly damaged that you must reinstall all apps, that is a step you must take. Use the second link in the Microsoft link below

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Note:  Keep Data also keeps the Windows User Profile and if the User Profile is damaged, you must reinstall Windows fresh.

Comment: Have tried that already , I do not see such an option as Keep everything

Comment: So your system is damaged badly. At this point, you must use the option to Keep Data. Be aware that Keep Data keeps your User Profile. If that is damaged, you must reinstall Windows.

Comment: How full is your system drive? In other words, how much free space do you still have?

Comment: Was able to upgrade my PC successfully using Midea Creation Link, with keeping data and apps safe.

Comment: So then the answer I gave you above has worked.